# Prove $||a|-|b| | \leq |a-b|$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Prove $||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$

I do it by making 4 cases :

Case 1 : $ a \geq 0$, $ b\geq 0$

So we have

$||a||-||b||  = |a - b|$ . hence proved

Case 2 :

$a < 0 , b< 0$

$|-a+b| = |-(a-b)|=|a-b|$

Case 3

$a >0, b<0$

$||a||-||b|| =|a+b| \leq |a|+|b| \leq a -b \leq |a-b| $

Case 4:

$a <0 ,b>0$

$|-a+b| = |-(a-b)| = |a-b|$

Is this OK ? Thanks

Comment: Why do you have twice absolute value?

Comment: I mean, vhat does $||a||$ stand for?

Comment: it is mod of mod x

Comment: What is mod?....

Comment: @ChristianF absolute value

Comment: Try a shortcut like $|a|=|b+(a-b)|\leq |b|+|a-b|$

Comment: First of all: if $||a||$ means taking the absolute value twice, then that's unnecessary since then $||a||=|a|$. Secondly: are you sure that's what it means? Because usually $||a||$ stands for the norm of $a$, where $a$ is a vector. Although if $a$ and $b$ are vectors, then $|a-b|$ is meaningless.

Comment: @JackM Edited question

Comment: The comment above by  rhybase is a complete answer. I dk why you don't write $ |a| $ instead of  $||a||.$.....$ ||a||$  is usually used for the norm in a multiple-dimension vector space..... BTW if you type \|a-b\| instead of ||a-b|| it comes out as  $\|a-b\| $  instead of  $ ||a-b||$  & it  is easier to read.

Comment: Where the OP writes $||a||-||b||$, they mean to write $||a|-|b||$.  The extra $|$'s are typos.

Comment: In case 3)$ ||a| - |b|| = |a + b|\le |a| + |b| = a - b$ (not $\le a-b$).  And You haven't cover if $a=0; b < 0$ (which for consistency you can make part of case three-- make case 3) $a \ge 0; b < 0$).  Other than those two comments look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two small comments:

In case three:  consider $a \ge 0; b< 0$  (otherwise you haven't covered the case where $a =0; b < 0$.)

An also in case three:  You state $|a| + |b| \le a - b$.  It's stronger to state $|a| + |b| = a-b$.

Other than that this is fine.

However in case 3) you refer to an earlier result  $|a+b| \le |a| + |b|$.  You should either explicitly mention that result or try to prove without it.

...

As an alternative prove as you *have* already proven $|a + b| \le |a|+|b|$ you might consider this slick proof:

$|a| = |a+b -b| \le |a-b| + |b|$ so $|a| - |b| \le |a-b|$.

Likewise $|b| = |a+b - a| \le |b-a| + |a|$ so $|b| - |a| \le |b-a| = |a-b|$

So $||a| -|b|| = \pm(|a| - |b|) \le |a-b|$.

Comment: For case 3 i use fact that $x \leq |x| $. Is my proof OK in general ? Also you say b=0 needs to be covered, then i suppose it needs to be covered for every case . Is it not? Also you wrote alternative proof which i have understood, but how do you come upon this proof? i mean why you have written what you have written

Comment: Also in case 4 i have $a <0 $and $b>0$. Do i have to make cases like 1 . a=0  and 2.  b=0in this ?

Comment: You have to do what works.  No more, no less.  The convention is $|x| = x$ when $x \ge 0$ and $|x| =-x$ if $x < 0$.  But of course it's also true that $|x| = -x$ if $x \le 0$.  But by convention the four cases are usually $a \ge 0; b\ge 0$ and $a\ge 0; b < 0$ and $a< 0; b\ge 0$ and $a< 0; b < 0$.  But if there is some *reason* to do a case for $a=0$ (usually trivial) separately or to do different cases.  Do what works.  But one way or another you should cover all cases.  You are right.  You don't have $b=0; a < 0$ and $a=0; b< 0$ covered.  BUt you don't need to do them separately.

Comment: Can you shed some light on alternate proof ?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a,b \in X,$ where $X$ is a normed linear space. By the triangle inequality, $|a| \le |a-b|+|b|,$ which implies $|a|-|b| \le |a-b|.$ Similarly $|b|-|a| \le |b-a|=|a-b|.$ The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

Observe $a.b \leq |a||b|$ then $|a-b|^2=(a-b)^2= a^2-2a.b+b^2 \geq |a|^2 -2|a||b| +|b|^2=(|a|-|b|)^2$ 
$\Rightarrow |a-b| \geq ||a|-|b||$

Comment: i do not understand $\geq$ in first step